# How can I dynamically create an instance of an class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

Example:

I have 10 view controllers, which are all allocated and initialized in the same way:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNib];
```

(note that -initWithNib is a custom method of a UIViewController subclass)

The next view controller class is OtherViewController, and so on. I want to load the view controllers lazily, just when I need them. But to do that, I need to have some kind of "array" that will give me the corresponding class for a given index, so that I can initialize it.

I ended up creating a method with a big switch-statement, that will just do that nasty allocation and initialization separately for every single view controller. I'm not happy with that. There it would be much better if I could assign the appropriate class to a variable, and then at the end of the switch statement just allocate and initialize that class from the variable.

Is there a way to achieve that?

EDIT: I've found a function

```
id class_createInstance(Class cls, size_t extraBytes)
```

and every class seems to have a property "class". But I can't assign it to an instance variable. This doesn't work:

```
Class cls = [UIImage class];
cls *image = [cls imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
```

The first line compiles. But the second one gives an error: "image undeclared".

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381793

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a basic factory pattern. You'd want to do: id image = [cls imageNamed:@"avatar.png"]. However, it's better to use a common base type here (i.e. UIImage* image = ...) as the first part of your question indicates that is the case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know the names of the classes at compile time, you can assign the classes to Class variables. For example:

```
static Class factory[2];

factory[0] = [MyViewController1 class];
factory[1] = [MyViewController2 class];
...
```

Then you could have (classid would be a constant known at compile time that would map to a desired class:

```
-(UIViewController*)createViewController:(int)classid
{
    return [[factory[classid] alloc] init];
}
```

Assuming that method is defined in a class named MyFactory, you can then do:

```
MyFactory * fac = [[MyFactory alloc] init];
UIViewController * v1 = [fac createViewController: 0]; // typed
id v2 = [fac createViewController: 1]; // untyped
```

If you don't have the compile time name of the class, you can simply do the following:

```
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>

id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"TheClassName") alloc] init];
```

Since your original question involves a set of UIViewControllers though, there's no reason to lose type safety with the latter method.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use reflection:

```
 id controller = class_createInstance(NSClassFromString(@"your class name"), 0/*extra bytes*/);
```

[Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_createInstance)

Comment: I'm getting a warning: "implicit declaration of function 'class_createInstance'"

Comment: #import <objc/objc-runtime.h>

Comment: @arul, is it possible to do [[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc] init]?

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this last month at:
http://igotosoft.blogspot.com/2009/05/dynamically-creating-viewscontrollers.html
Essentially, it involves a new class I call the ClassConstructor, which takes a class name, init method name, and comma separated arguments. When you need to create an instance of that class, just use your [myClassConstructor create];

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Reflection.  No idea of objective-c has it though - but the term might help you Google for your answer better.

Comment: -1???  Give me a break - it's a completely correct answer and was also the only answer initially after an hour.  Just because you don't know a specific language doesn't mean an answer is incorrect - it very well could have helped another user to answer the question.  Some of the people on this site need to take themselves less seriously, or find a new hobby.

Comment: There's always people who are going to vote down any answer they see as unfit for any reason. You get far more credit for an upvote than a downvote costs you. Just don't let it bother you, it's bad for the blood pressure.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective C Reference also will be a good place to look to get the calls. Try searching for Objective-C 2.0 Runtime Reference since I cant add links